# Hard to understand Leetcode 140 solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

For this problem from LeetCode https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/ I have seen the next solution:

```
class Solution {
private:
    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> dp;
public:
    vector<string> wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
        if(dp.find(s) != dp.end())
            return dp[s];
        vector<string> result;
        for(string w : wordDict)
        {
            if(s.substr(0, w.length()) == w)
            {
                if(w.length() == s.length())
                    result.push_back(w);
                else
                {
                    vector<string> temp = wordBreak(s.substr(w.length()), wordDict);
                    for(string t : temp)
                        result.push_back(w + " " + t);
                }
            }
        }
        dp[s] = result;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Can somebody help me understand how it works? I find this recursion hard to follow.

Comment: In general competition code is NOT written to be understood. It's intended to be written quickly and run fast once on specific hardware. All too often it's not worth learning from.

Comment: The best way to understand code is to start it in debugger and step line by line through the code.

Comment: Did you tried to use debugger to see how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easier to understand:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string s = "pineapplepenapple";
int n;
unordered_set<string> dict({"apple", "pen", "applepen", "pine", "pineapple"});

void solve(vector<string> &v, int index = 0){
    if(index >= n){
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            cout<<v[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = index; i < n; i++){
        string sub = s.substr(index, i - index + 1);
        if(dict.find(sub) != dict.end()){
            v.push_back(sub);
            solve(v, i + 1);
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<string> v;
    n = s.size();
    solve(v);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
pine apple pen apple 
pine applepen apple 
pineapple pen apple
```

---

I'll break `solve` in pieces to explain it better.

```cpp
void solve(vector<string> &v, int index = 0){
```

`v` stores each valid word in order to print in the end. `index` is the char we are looking at the moment.

```cpp
    if(index >= n){
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            cout<<v[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
```

This is the base case of the recursion, when the index is bigger or equal to the size of the string itself, meaning it reached the end of it.

```cpp
    for(int i = index; i < n; i++){
        string sub = s.substr(index, i - index + 1);
        if(dict.find(sub) != dict.end()){
            v.push_back(sub);
            solve(v, i + 1);
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

This `for` loop looks at each substring of the original string (starting from index), for example: `p`, `pi`, `pin`, `pine`, ..., and when one of these substrings are in the dictionary, the put it into `v` and call the method again, starting in the index right after where that substring ended.

Lastly, when the recursion comes back, we remove the substring from `v`, because we want to try the other ones.

The difference from the provided solution to this one is that the provided solution uses dynamic programming to store how many possibilities there are with each substring, so it doesnt need to compute `solve(a, b)` again if it was already computed before. This shouldn't be hard for you to extend.